# How to run the Performance monitor for unlimited time

Tags: windows, performance, perfmon

How can I run the performance monitor for unlimited time? (about 2-3 weeks)

Comment: Specifically on scheduling: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722312.aspx  though if you want the whole how to on performance monitor, start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx